# Mushroom Cloud Using Cocos2d

Tags: graphics, cocos2d-iphone, particle-system

I would like to display an animated mushroom cloud (probably with particle emitters) as the result of an explosion in an iPad game I am developing.

I was wondering if there was anyone out there that has already tried this, and if they would be willing to give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trainyard by Matt Rix has a little explosion animation that happens when a train crashes.  You could ask him